# How to merge two arrays by creating a new array and print the result ? (with codes)

Tags: php

I get the contents of rss feeds, but for my bad luck they have different structure. With the help of the community I got over this problem though.

My question is how can I combine $entries1 and $entries2 into $entries3 ? What I will achieve is to handle and sort all feeds with different structure.

Thank you.

FIRST CODE

```
<?php
$feeds1 = array('','','');
$entries1 = array();
foreach ($feeds1 as $feed1) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed1);
    $entries1 = array_merge($entries1, $xml->xpath('/rss/channel//item'));
} 
echo "<pre>"; print_r($entries1); echo"</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, missed some details in your post when I answered... Whats the result of the above code when the arrays are not empty? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, I believe you would simply use `array_merge()` ...

```
$entries3 = array_merge($entries1, $entries2);
```

or even

```
$entries6 = array_merge($entries1, $entries2, $entries3, $entries4, $entries5);
```

or am I just not understanding this question?