# Echo the values of an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

How can I echo for example the title of the following array? (entries). Using print_r I get this ( I post only a part of it).
I would like to create a variable for each item I want to echo, this will help me on doing some modifications on it before showing the result.

Thank you stackoverflow!

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [guid] => tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-8508477708802179245.post-7592005355313594438
            [pubDate] => Sun, 29 May 2011 12:05:00 +0000
            [category] => Thoughts
            [title] => Should I go for it ?
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your code looks -very- similar to Mairys:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300042/how-to-merge-two-arrays-by-creating-a-new-array-and-print-the-result-with-code

Comment: We are working on the same project but she just left for tonight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I echo for example the title of the following array?

Subscript the first array element, and then access its `title` property...

```
echo $entries[0]->title;
```

> I would like to create a variable for each item I want to `echo`

You could do this manually...

```
$title = $entries[0]->title;
```

Or do it automatically with `extract()`...

```
extract((array) $entries[0], EXTR_SKIP);
```

Be careful with `extract()`. It won't overwrite existing variables with the `EXTR_SKIP` flag, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Thank you. How can i echo all titles ?

Comment: @JBEnergy Loop with `foreach` over `$entries`.

Comment: I just saw your edit. Is there a way to use the echo $entries[0]->title; and show all the titles. With a loop maybe ?

Comment: Haha what a timing! Thank you alex!