# Is the image an attribute or I have to use a regex to get it?

Tags: php, xml, regex

I am trying to get the first image of each post of a feed. An image is always exists inside each `<description>` as below

```
<description>&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="http://lh5.ggpht.com/-kDNySEwupXc/Tesp_XbEXQI/AAAAAAAAKZY/t5TMtq7SkCs/s1600-h/image%25255B4%25255D.png"&gt;&lt; ....></description>
```

I get the title, author and other content as below

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

echo "<pre>"; echo $entry->title; echo" -- "; echo $entry->author; echo" -- "; echo $entry->pubDate; echo"<br>"; echo "</pre>";

}
```

but I do not know if the image is an attribute inside the description. If it is so how can I show it? I guess this solution is much easier and faster than using a regular expression like this one to get the first image :

```
preg_match('!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui'
```

If the regex is the only solution, how can I use it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the *always reliable* method of using a DOM parser.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadXML(html_entity_decode($entry->description));

$imageSrc = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/xdUh37NW).

You may want to expand the code a bit to handle missing `a` element (check `lengtg` property) or missing `href` attribute (use `hasAttribute()` method).

Comment: Hi again alex. I am trying to implement it with my existing code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300362/echo-the-values-of-an-array-in-php and I will come back to you

Comment: @alex as I saw on your codepad it works fine. My question/problem is how can I add it into the foreach loop and echo the imageSrc ?

Comment: @JBEnergy Place the code inside the body of the `foreach`. Pass the correct string, I have used `$entry->description` but that was a guess. I ignored regex all together.

Comment: @JBEnergy You have not defined `$entries`, nor have you used the PHP start tag. Fix that up and I'll take another look.